# How to de-attach the output of child processes in C?

Tags: c, terminal

For an university assignment, we have to build and implement our own terminal using C and POSIX. We've gotten quite far, with all basic terminal commands working, and are currently working on job control.

Terminating and pausing jobs works fine, as well as other parts, but we have gotten quite stuck in trying to find out how to stop a process that's put to the background in our terminal from printing to the standard output. Unfortunately, I've been having a tough time finding posts that already addressed how to do this, so I figured I'd ask the question myself!

In short: Our terminal can run processes, such as for example "count.c" , which will keep counting infinitely. We can put this process to the background successfully, however, on the background, it will keep generating output to stdout, which then blocks our terminal. In short, *how do we stop the output stream of child processes, while keeping the program running?*

We did notice that pipes exist, but we are having a lot of trouble with the syntax of setting those up nor were we quite sure if they are the solution to what we need. Our program must use execv() and fork() specifically, is something that should be mentioned. We also tried investigating if there was any way to do this outside of pipes, but we could not find much.

Comment: It is normal for a background process to continue writing to the terminal from which it was spawned.  Why do you want to suppress that behavior?  If you want the process to not write to the terminal, you typically redirect its output stream somewhere else rather than trying to change how the process behaves.

Comment: "it will keep generating output to stdout, which then blocks our terminal". What do you mean by "blocks"?  You can invoke programs with stdout to a pipe instead of a terminal, but many comands will introspect stdout to determine whether it's a terminal (eg colorized output, human formatting), so sending stdout to a pipe instead, will change the behavior of things like `ls`

Comment: "We've gotten quite far, with all basic terminal commands working, and are currently working on job control." None of these things are implemented by terminals. It sounds like you're implementing a shell, not a terminal.

Comment: Examples of terminals: `gnome-terminal` and `xterm`. Examples of shells: `bash`, `sh`, `zsh`, `ksh`.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply

-> "It is normal for a background process to continue writing to the terminal"... turns out, it is. I didn't realise this beforehand, thank you for mentioning it! Turns out, we indeed do not need to do that, we misunderstood the assignment. So that's quite a bit of work saved.

Comment: -> "it will keep generating output to stdout, which then blocks our terminal", with that I meant that you would be unable to continue typing into the terminal, nor can you directly pause or terminate this job through our terminal since it would not be the foreground job, meaning one would have to force shut down the terminal when an infinitely running program is called

Comment: -> You're right, I meant to describe a shell! Apologies for getting those two mixed up, I didn't realise they were different, I was referring to the linux terminal I use through wsl, as it seemed similar in function to what we are implementing